# eclipse scala project : how to access to a file inside the project

Tags: java, scala, path, directory, spray

I have a spray app but the spray aspect is not important.

My web app has the directory : src/main/scala in which there is the package models.
In a code I have this statement:

```
lazy val xml = ElémentXML("models.exemple_bon.xml")
```

The object ElémentXML has for argument a string which is the local name of a file that should be in the models directory, but the call fails.

The code in ElémentXML is as here:

```
try {
          val xml_chargé = xml.XML.loadFile(fichier)
          Some(new ElémentXML(xml_chargé, fichier))
        } catch {
          case e: Throwable => None
        }
```

The error is as here:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: models.exemple_bon.xml (No such file or directory)
```

can you help me?

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly the problem is. Is the error message the problem or does the file exist but isn't found? Or is there a problem with the XML Api?

Comment: hello, the lazy val is in a test which does not pass because of the file not found : this is the problem, and I confirm that the file exists in the right package.

Comment: I guess your xml is located in `classpath`. Then you can use `classloader(or this.getClass).getResourceAsStream` to access that file